# Mirrored Arabic Letters using TextClip Moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am trying to render the video which contains arabic letters. let's use مرحبا for the example. After video rendered the result is mirrored.

```
background = mp.ColorClip(mobile_size, (255, 255, 255), duration=0.5) #float(audiolength.info.length)
text1 = mp.TextClip(english, fontsize=45, color=fcolor, font=Font, size= (mobile_size[0], 185), method = 'caption', align="south").set_duration(0.5) #float(audiolength.info.length)
text2 = mp.TextClip(formatChineseSentences(translated).encode("utf-8"), fontsize=45, color=fcolor2, font=Font, size= (mobile_size[0], 185), method = 'caption', align="north").set_duration(0.5) #float(audiolength.info.length)

clip1 = mp.CompositeVideoClip([background, text1.set_position(('center', "top")), text2.set_position(('center', "bottom"))])
```

Expected Behavior

[image: Correct Arrabic Letter]

Actual Behavior

[image: Mirrored Arabic Letter]

Steps to Reproduce the Problem

Rendering TextClip with Arabic Characters. For this case we can use مرحبا.

Specifications

Python Version: Python 3.8.5
Moviepy Version: 1.0.3
Platform Name: Mac OS Catalina
Platform Version: 10.15.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution is to reshape and reverse the font.

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

def formatArabicSentences(sentences):
   formatedSentences = arabic_reshaper.reshape(sentences)
   return get_display(formatedSentences)
```